# Restlet WebService returning a PDF

Tags: restlet

I have a Restlet Web Service that is returning a PDF document and the client side needs to receive this docuement and display it.

Server Side Code:

```
orderNumber = f.getFirstValue(PARAM_ORDER_NUMBER);
orderType = f.getFirstValue(PARAM_ORDER_TYPE).toUpperCase();

String fileName = OrderDM.getPDF(orderNumber, orderType);

pdfRep = new FileRepresentation(new File(fileName), MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF, 0);
return pdfRep;
```

Client Side:

```
ClientResource client = getClientResource(PRINTER_FRIENDLY_DOCUMENT_RESOURCE);
Reference reference = client.getReference();

reference.addQueryParameter(PARAM_ORDER_TYPE, orderType);
reference.addQueryParameter(PARAM_ORDER_NUMBER, orderNumber);

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
client.get().write(outputStream);
byte[] fileContent = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Will this work and is this the best way to do this.

Comment: I do the same on server side and that works fine. But for the client side, I have to display the file in the browser so I just open a new browser window that references the resource on the server and let the browser handle the bytestream.